# Ranking posts according to attention gained over a given period of time

Tags: algorithms

This is my 1st question here, I am a software dev but almost a complete newbie when it comes to math, I am trying to solve a handful of challenges using my primitive knowledge so any side notes, tips, resources to help me in my learning are all welcome.

The problem:

Some time ago I made an application that would rank posts depending how "useful" they were to the users, users would tap a button on the post to indicate that they found it useful.

Now there were posts that gained say, 25 points over 6 weeks and others gained lets say, 20 over 6 days. These two obviously are not equal in rank, the one that gained that attention much faster has to have an upper hand.

Anyway, I tried quite a while and for my 1st attempt I came up with this.

[image: My try]

So now my intuition says that the smaller the return value of this function the more rank the post should get. What I don't understand is how to model this inverse relationship between the average point frequency and the rank.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Should it be average time between each point?

Comment: It does not HAVE to be, but that's one thing I thought that might work to get the desired result. Any other approach is welcome as well.